# How to avoid multiple, almost identical, subqueries in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need get the result of two almost identical subqueries and I'm wondering if there is a way to do it without the inefficiency of executing the subquery twice.

```
SELECT
DISTINCT(liens.lienID),
ROUND(liens.lienSettlementAmount, 2) as lienSettlementAmount,
(SELECT
 ROUND(SUM(lienBills.amount), 2)
 FROM lienBills2Lien
 LEFT JOIN lienBills ON lienBills2Lien.lienBillID = lienBills.lienBillID
 WHERE lienBills2Lien.lienID = liens.lienID
 ) AS totalBill,
(SELECT
 ROUND(SUM(lienBills.amount), 2) - lienSettlementAmount
 FROM lienBills2Lien
 LEFT JOIN lienBills ON lienBills2Lien.lienBillID = lienBills.lienBillID
 WHERE lienBills2Lien.lienID = liens.lienID
 ) AS savings

FROM events
RIGHT JOIN liens ON events.childID = liens.lienID

WHERE events.fileNumber = 14275
AND events.eventTypeID = 79
```

The only difference is the subtraction of lienSettlementAmount in the 2nd subquery.

This query gives me exactly what I need but it just does not feel right. It seems there should be a better way.

UPDATE: @StanislavL has the correct answer. Here is the exact code:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT(liens.lienID),
   ROUND(liens.lienSettlementAmount, 2) as lienSettlementAmount,
   sub.r_sum as totalBill,
   sub.r_sum - lienSettlementAmount as savings
FROM events
RIGHT JOIN liens ON events.childID = liens.lienID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT lienBills2Lien.lienID,
            ROUND(SUM(lienBills.amount), 2) AS r_sum
            FROM lienBills2Lien
            LEFT JOIN lienBills ON lienBills2Lien.lienBillID = lienBills.lienBillID
            GROUP BY lienBills2Lien.lienID
          ) sub ON sub.lienID = liens.lienID
WHERE events.fileNumber = 14275
AND events.eventTypeID = 79
```

However, Execution time for this with the single subquery is higher. This query takes 0.0205 sec. Mine with two subqueries takes 0.0054 sec. I did not expect this result.

Why would the single subquery be slower? Maybe this should be a separate question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT(liens.lienID),
   sub.r_sum as totalBill,
   sub.r_sum-lienSettlementAmount as savings,
FROM events
RIGHT JOIN liens ON events.childID = liens.lienID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT lienBills2Lien.lienID
            ROUND(SUM(lienBills.amount), 2)  as r_sum
            FROM lienBills2Lien
            LEFT JOIN lienBills ON lienBills2Lien.lienBillID = lienBills.lienBillID
            GROUP BY lienBills2Lien.lienID
          ) sub ON sub.lienID= liens.lienID
```

JUst move the subquery to FROM and add JOIN

Answer (score 0):

I can figure out this query form:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(liens.lienID), 
ROUND(liens.lienSettlementAmount, 2) as lienSettlementAmount, 
(SELECT 
    ROUND(SUM(lienBills.amount), 2) AS totalBill,
    ROUND(SUM(lienBills.amount), 2) - lienSettlementAmount AS savings
    FROM lienBills2Lien LEFT JOIN lienBills ON lienBills2Lien.lienBillID = lienBills.lienBillID
    WHERE lienBills2Lien.lienID = liens.lienID)
FROM events RIGHT JOIN liens ON events.childID = liens.lienID WHERE events.fileNumber = 14275 AND events.eventTypeID = 79;
```

Here you only have a subquery. I would really like to know if you get the same needed result.

Regards

Comment: No go. Your query returns more than one field from the subquery. As I understand it, subqueries can only return one field. Good try though. :)

Comment: I just tried to run it and got the same issue. Sorry. I hope @StanislavL got it right.